# How to paste in the next column and the next row empty

Tags: excel, vba

I need to start pasting in column G second row X Qty of values, if there are more than 1, this should continue pasting to the next column, e.g:

2 Values

Start at second row in column G and then paste the next value in second row column H.

Then for the next item

Should start at third row in column G and then paste the next value in third row column H.

I tried many examples but nothings works, this is the code which im trying now.

```html
Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

ActiveCell.Value = imgsrc
```

[image: Image Example]

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code than the single line please?

Comment: I don't have too much at code, I just take an result (link) from an item, and I want to paste in the next empty row in Column G, and if that item has an second image, the paste in the next empty row column H.

So for the second item, do the same, starting at column G first empty row and if it has another image, then paste in the next empty row next column, in this case should be the H

I just edited the main question, an attached image example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I just used an double check to cell with an if.

```html
Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

If ActiveCell <> "" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                                 
ActiveCell.Value = "X"

End If
                                  
If ActiveCell = "" Then
                                    
ActiveCell.Value = "X"

End If
```